# Accessing call start time in Rails from Adhearsion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, adhearsion

I have built a Rails application and connected with Adhearsion for outbound calls via url (virginia). I need to get the time at which the outbound call is answered. How can I get that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Call object has an instance method `end_time`

Returns the time at which the call began. For inbound calls this is the time at which the call was offered to Adhearsion. For outbound calls it is the time at which the remote party answered.

Returns:
(Time) — the time at which the call began. For inbound calls this is the time at which the call was offered to Adhearsion. For outbound calls it is the time at which the remote party answered.

Described in the documentation here... http://rubydoc.info/gems/adhearsion/Adhearsion/Call